# Can't deploy war file containing primefaces to websphere

Tags: java, deployment, primefaces, websphere, war

I created a JSF war file containing xhtml page and managed bean. Its lib folder containing the following jars:

- `myfaces-api-2.2.13.jar`
- `myfaces-impl-2.2.13.jar`
- `commons-xxxxxx.jar`
- `jstl-1.2.jar`

It's working fine when I deploy it on Webshpere 8.5.5.

I need to add primefaces to my project. After adding primefaces jar file (`primefaces-6.0.jar`) under war lib folder and deploy it on the Websphere it gives me this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
  javax/faces/component/UIComponent.getPassThroughAttributes(Z)Ljava/util/Map;
```

Note: it's working fine (with primefaces) when tested it on Tomcat v7.0 in Eclipse.

I generated the war by exporting it from Eclipse.

Comment: This must be related to the version of JSF provided by the container. Likely that your primefaces expects a newer version of JSF than the one handed to you by WAS. Try including in your archive a JSF implementation (making sure your classloader is not set to parent first)

Comment: PrimeFaces 6 should run fine on JSF 2.0-2.2 and the method is from JSF 2.2 so that is weird... Sure there is no 'attempt' in a page to user passtrough attributes? Is it an error from the deployment? Than **always** post stacktraces..

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the instructions [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tweb_jsf.html) to configure your third party JavaServer Faces implementation. It looks as though you are including JSF 2.2 libraries within your application. The method that can't be found was added in JSF 2.2 [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getPassThroughAttributes--). WebSphere 8.5.5 offers EE6 compliance and the following JSF versions are available: SunRI 1.2 and MyFaces 2.0. It would seem a JSF 2.2 implementation is required in this instance, more than likely the application is using pass through attributes and requires the JSF 2.2 libraries. My initial thought is that primefaces detects the 2.2 libraries in the application but the WebSphere runtime JSF version is being picked up at runtime and hence the error.

Comment: so you are saying by default a prehistoric jsf version is used in WebSphere 8.5.5?

Comment: Updated my answer to give additional clarification